# Creating an advanced dynamic formula calculator in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, calculator

Is it possible to create a dynamic formula calculator in excel for a formula like this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/how-to-calculate-pooled-variance-of-two-or-more-groups-given-known-group-varianc (see top answer).

I want to be able to specify how many SDs or means I am combining and make excel create and calculate the extra cells that are added dynamically, if this makes sense.

Comment: Unclear question but yes it's possible without looking much in details of the question. Excel is built for mathematics, so I would be very surprised if you had a formula that is impossible.

Comment: What has been shown in links have has a possible function in Excel,,, and up to certain extend mathematics can be solved also using cell references,, but what would be better please [Edit] your post and upload some sample data & expected output !!

Comment: "this makes sense" ? yes. | Would you mind sharing a sample (and simple) input matrix/list with its weightage to test it ( so that the case reproducible in excel , and hand calculation verified..) ? ( :